# props.onClick undefined checkbox React Native

Tags: react-native, checkbox

I am using the Checkbox component for my code and I have a list of elements and for each element I have a checkbox. However, my checkbox returns the following error when I check it on the phone simulator :

```
TypeError: this.props.onClick is not a function. (In 'this.props.onClick()', 'this.props.onClick' is undefined)
```

I don't understand because a checkbox does not require the onClick function ...

Please see my code below if needed:

```
import CheckBox from 'react-native-check-box'

export default class List extends Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props)

   this.state = {
      names: [
         {
            key: 0,
            name: 'Element1',
            isChecked: false
         },
         {
            key: 1,
            name: 'Element2',
            isChecked: false, 
         }
      ]
   }
}

   checkboxTest(key){
      let names = this.state.names.reduce((acc,name)=>{
         if(name.key === key){
            return {...name, isChecked: !name.isChecked}
         }
         return name
      }, [])
      this.setState({names})
      console.table(names)
   }


   render(){
      return (
        <ScrollView>

         <View>
            {
               this.state.names.map((item) => (
                <View style={styles.background}>  
                <Text style = {styles.title}>{item.name}</Text>
                <CheckBox value={false} onChange={()=>this.checkboxTest(item.key)}/>
                </View>
               ))
            }
         </View>
         </ScrollView> 
      ) 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `react-native-check-box` documentation prop `onClick` is isRequired. But you are passing `onChange` not `onClick`.

Change your `onChange` to `onClick` in order to fix the error. Also change `value` to `isChecked`.

```
<CheckBox isChecked={false} onClick={()=>this.checkboxTest(item.key)}/>
```

**Edit**

Check below complete example for information

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import CheckBox from "react-native-check-box";

export default class List extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      names: [
        {
          key: 0,
          name: "Element1",
          isChecked: false
        },
        {
          key: 1,
          name: "Element2",
          isChecked: false
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  checkboxTest = key => {
    let names = this.state.names.reduce((acc, name) => {
      if (name.key === key) {
        acc.push({ ...name, isChecked: !name.isChecked });
      } else {
        acc.push(name);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
    this.setState({ names });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.state.names.map((item, index) => (
          <View style={{ flexDirection: " row" }}>
            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
            <CheckBox
              isChecked={
                this.state.names.find(item => item.key == index).isChecked
              }
              onClick={() => this.checkboxTest(item.key)}
            />
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-check-box) carefully, you will noticed that this checkbox component requires a `onClick` function, which you did not provide. Hence, instead of writing `onChange`, you should be using `onClick` instead

```js
<CheckBox
    style={{flex: 1, padding: 10}}
    onClick={()=>{
      this.setState({
          isChecked:!this.state.isChecked
      })
    }}
    isChecked={this.state.isChecked}
    leftText={"CheckBox"}
/>
```